# Is it possible to check if custom dimension exists in universal google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Here is how I set a custom dimension for the life of the tracker object in GA:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'custom data');
```

but is there a way to check if such dimension exists or if the dimension with such value exists?

Maybe something like? :

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var dimension = tracker.get('dimension1');
  console.log(dimension);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not without authenticating. But once you [authenticate the JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js), you can use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list) to see what Custom Dimensions are defined for a given property.

```
var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.customDimensions.list({
    'accountId': '123456',
    'webPropertyId': 'UA-123456-1'
});
request.execute(manageCustomDimensions);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't completely follow what the `manageCustomDimensions` variable is, though, and can't seem to find any info about it in the docs.

Comment: It is a function that accepts the response as a parameter